# Is it possible to capture packets of router which i connected through wifi of my laptop

Tags: router, wireshark, packet

I want to capture all traffic of router I can only connect with wifi no physical access and I do have access to configuration page of router

Comment: It depends on the router firmware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) should do exactly what you are looking for. It will monitor your network interface for all traffic on said network.

I'm not sure if you're using Linux or Windows but run it as root/administrator for best results.

You can [filter](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters) which packets to look for from a myriad of options.

More functionality can be found on the wiki.